# how to display the data depending on the selection made at 2 drop down lists?

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

```
<?php 
include('config.php'); 
$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">Parent Category</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Sub Category</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>

    <td><label>
                        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Search" />
                      </label></td>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

/*the above is the index.php file.
after I click search button, I want some data to be displayed depending on the selections made at 2 drop down lists. and the data should be fetched from the database..*/

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly ?

Comment: @sanketh i have a db containing state, district, neighbouring district, year etc etc... and i 've made 2 drop down boxes for state and districts... when i select state and district from the drop down list, the details regarding the selected district should be displayed... i hope u got it!!!!!

Comment: How is the database organized exactly?